# Python Web Socket AttributeError: type object '_socketobject' has no attribute 'gethostbyname'

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, attributeerror

Trying my hand at python web sockets for the first time and stuck on this bug:

AttributeError: type object '_socketobject' has no attribute 'gethostbyname'

```
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 80)) 
serverSocket.listen(5)
while True:
    print 'Ready to serve.'
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept() 
    print 'connection is from', addr
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(2048)
        filename = message.split()[1]
        print filename
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n')
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        print 'IOError'
        connectionSocket.send('HelloWorld.html')
        connectionSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
```

Also, if you have any recommendations for libraries to use to make this easier/more like something you'd actually write, I'd much appreciate the input.

Comment: I should mention, I'm using Anaconda 2.5.0 (x86_64)

Answer (score 1):

Since you imported the whole `socket` module into your namespace, you do not need to write `socket.` before your call to the `gethostname` function. Simplify the third line of your code like so: `serverSocket.bind((gethostname(), 80))`